# Preorder traversal of expression tree

Tags: c++, tree, preorder

This function prints the preorder traversal of expression tree

```
void PreOrder(Node root) {
    if (root)  
    {     
        cout<< root->data<<" "; 
        PreOrder(root->left); 
        PreOrder(root->right);
    } 
    
}
```

**But want to return pre order traversal of expression tree as a string.** but the following code compiles successfully but it does not give any output.

```
string PreOrder(Node root) {
string s="";
    if (root)  
    { 
        s=s+root->data;
        PreOrder(root->left); 
        PreOrder(root->right); 
    } 
    return s;
}
```

how should I solve it.

Comment: What happens with the strings that the recursive calls ***returns***?

Comment: Yes. In main function I did

Answer (score 2):

You need to also use the result of the recursive calls to `PreOrder`:

```
s += PreOrder(root->left); 
s += PreOrder(root->right);
```